# ADB pull to get all contents of a directory but not the directory from android and copy to windows

Tags: android, copy, adb, pull

I am trying to copy all directories and files from an android device within a specified location

ie: /sdcard/Android/data/com.company.software/data/XXXXXXX

XXXXXXXX is all contents of directory

To a local directory C:\copied\android

when using

```
    adb -s %%G pull "/sdcard/Android/data/com.company.software/data" C:/copied/android
```

It will copy the data directory and its contents and place in C:\copied\android\data\XXXXXXX

I have tried with and without the trailing / but doesn't seem to make any difference and * doesn't seem to play nice either.

what i want to occur is the contents to directly go to the C:\copied\android\ folder.

ie. C:\copied\android\XXXXXXXXX

Wondering if there is a way to do this or do I have to copy locally then move them?

Thanks

Comment: `XXXXXXXX is all contents of directory` ???? If you write `/sdcard/Android/data/com.company.software/data/XXXXXXX` then XXXXXXXX is the last subdirectory and not some contents. Please adhere to normal notation.

Comment: Would this be easier:
/sdcard/Android/data/com.company.software/data/folder1/file1
/sdcard/Android/data/com.company.software/data/folder1/file2
/sdcard/Android/data/com.company.software/data/folder1/file3
/sdcard/Android/data/com.company.software/data/folder2/file1
/sdcard/Android/data/com.company.software/data/folder2/file2
/sdcard/Android/data/com.company.software/data/folder2/file3
/sdcard/Android/data/com.company.software/data/folder3/file1
/sdcard/Android/data/com.company.software/data/folder3/file2
/sdcard/Android/data/com.company.software/data/folder3/file3

Comment: I am looking to copy folder1 and its contents, folder2 and its contents, folder3 and its contents directly to C:\copied\android\

It currently copies it to:
C:\copied\android\data\folder1\file1
C:\copied\android\data\folder1\file2
C:\copied\android\data\folder1\file3
C:\copied\android\data\folder2\file1
C:\copied\android\data\folder2\file2
C:\copied\android\data\folder2\file3
C:\copied\android\data\folder3\file1
C:\copied\android\data\folder3\file2
C:\copied\android\data\folder3\file3

Comment: You should have said: i want to copy data directory `/sdcard/Android/data/com.company.software/data` to `C:\copied\android`.

Comment: And to make it more clear you could have said: the result should be `C:\copied\android\data`

Comment: I'm looking to copy the contents of /data/ - files and directories (all of its contents) directly to the copied\android\ directory locally.

But I'm only able to copy the /data/ directory with its contents vs just the contents

Comment: Then you should have said: i want to copy the contents of data directory.... Hmmm... You also did that...

Comment: Apologies for adding xxx. You are correct I want to copy directory /sdcard/Android/data/com.company.software/data to C:\copied\android

I'm by far a programmer and don't know all the standard annotations. Hence the monologue describing what you did in a sentence.

Comment: I know nothing of adb commands... Sorry.

Comment: `sdcard/Android/data/com.company.software/data` change for a try to `sdcard/Android/data/com.company.software/data/*.*`

Comment: Sadly no, ADB does not play nice with wildcards and directories